# Facebook circular redirect path open graph error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I would like to ask why facebook response returns 301. Im using prerender.io for generating static html however when try to scrape the content using facebook open debug it doesnt recognizr my meta tags which im sure it has

[image]

Comment: Hey Sydney did you ever resolve this?